# Zipar arquivos com o mesmo nome dentro de uma pasta

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

Gostaria de saber se existe a posbilidade de ser feito o seguinte cenario em Delhpi:

Tenho uma pasta e dentro dela tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
foto.jpg
foto.png
imagem.jpg
imagem.png
```

é possivel zipar, pelo nome? sendo assim... zipar somente os arquivos que conteham o mesmo nome...resultando em:

```
foto.zip -> contem -> foto.jpg e foto.png
imagem.zip -> contem -> imagem.jpg e imagem.png
```

Não quero uma resposta pronta, mas sim a viabiliadde de fazer isso em Delphi, lembrando que os arquivos eu posso não saber o nome deles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a classe [System.Zip.TZipFile](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Zip.TZipFile) do proprio delphi para fazer esta implementação, fazendo um loop nos arquivos com o mesmo nome (com extensões diferentes) e adicionando eles no zip conforme a regra que você definir, segue o exemplo com base na pergunta:

```
uses
  System.SysUtils,
  StrUtils,
  Classes,
  System.Zip;

var
  vArquivos: TStringList;
  vDiretorio: String;
  vDiretorioSaida: String;
  searchResult : TSearchRec;
  vArquivoSemExtensao: String;
  I: Integer;
  ZipFile: TZipFile;
begin
  vDiretorio := 'D:\Arquivos';
  vDiretorioSaida := 'D:\ArquivosZipado';
  vArquivos := TStringList.Create;
  try
    if findfirst(vDiretorio+'\*.*', faAnyFile, searchResult) = 0 then
    begin
      repeat
        vArquivos.Sort;
        if (searchResult.Name <> '.') and (searchResult.Name <> '..') then
        begin
          vArquivoSemExtensao := ChangeFileExt(searchResult.Name, '');
          if not vArquivos.Find(vArquivoSemExtensao, I) Then
            vArquivos.Add(vArquivoSemExtensao);
        end;
      until FindNext(searchResult) <> 0;
    end;
    FindClose(searchResult);

    for I := 0 to vArquivos.Count -1 do
    begin
      ZipFile := TZipFile.Create;
      try
        ZipFile.Open(vDiretorioSaida+'\'+vArquivos.Strings[I]+'.zip', zmWrite);
        if findfirst(vDiretorio+'\'+vArquivos.Strings[I]+'.*', faAnyFile, searchResult) = 0 then
        begin
          repeat
            ZipFile.add(vDiretorio+'\'+searchResult.Name);
          until (FindNext(searchResult) <> 0);
        end;
        FindClose(searchResult);
      finally
        FreeAndNil(ZipFile);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(vArquivos);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Execelente, só uma duvida... em vez vDiretorio+'\*.* aceitar todo tipo de arquivo...seria possivel aceitar somente um tipo? por exemplo só png e jpg.. tentei passar  *.jpg|*.png..mas ele n reconhece.

Comment: Fiz um teste aqui e ele realmente não deixa passar mais de uma extensão no findfirst, uma opção seria dentro do repeat da busca de arquivos utilizar a função ExtractFileExt passando como parâmetro o searchResult.Name, assim você consegue saber a extensão do arquivo e fazer a tratativa que desejar.

Answer (score -1):

Sim é possível, no caso utilizei o WinRAR mas com o zip funciona também

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a "E:\Backup\foto.rar" "E:\Backup\foto.*"
```

Se você utilizar o "*" no lugar da extensão, todos os arquivos com o nome "foto" independente da extensão será compactado...

Se tiver alguma dúvida pode dar uma olhada [aqui](https://terminaldeinformacao.com/2017/02/01/como-utilizar-winrar-pelo-prompt-de-comando/)

Comment: interessante a abordagem, mas posso não saber o nome do arquivo que está na pasta

Comment: Mas como você vai compactar os arquivos por nome então? Você precisaria saber a extensão ou o nome dos arquivos pelo menos

Comment: exato, por nome... eu pensei em algo como dercorrer a pasta e localizar todos que tem o mesmo nome e eai sim zipar..

Comment: Então, você apenas tem que percorrer a pasta, guardando cada nome de arquivo (os repetidos você grava um só), então você pega e executa o método que falei pra cada um dos nomes gravados. Como você disse, eu não dei uma resposta pronta, mas sim uma parte dela... Você consegue, pelo delphi, percorrer os arquivos da pasta e pegar o nome de cada um deles